# how to make the date change to TimeStamp in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {
collection,
addDoc,
Timestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase-config";

function Register({ setIsAuth }) {

let navigate = useNavigate();
const VoltarLogin = () => {
    navigate("/login");
};

const [registerEmail, setRegisterEmail] = useState("");
const [registerPassword, setRegisterPassword] = useState("");

const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [curso, setCurso] = useState("");
const [birthDate, setBirthDate] = useState(Timestamp.fromDate(new 
 Date()));

const userCollectionRef = collection(db, "usuarios");

const handleRegister = async () => {
    try {
        const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            registerEmail,
            registerPassword
        ).then((result) => {
            localStorage.setItem("isAuth", true);
            setIsAuth(true);
            navigate("/home");
        })
        await addDoc(userCollectionRef, {
            tipoUsuario: 'aluno',
            idUsuario: auth.currentUser.uid,
            nome,
            email,
            curso,
            dataNascimento: birthDate,
        });
        console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

 return (
<div className="box">
<div className="center-box-register">
    <div className="card-register">
        <h1>Cadastro</h1>
    <div className="linha">
    </div>

                <div className="textfield">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Nome:</label>
                    <input 
                    type="text"
                    name="nome"
                    id="nome"
                    placeholder="Digite seu nome"
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setNome(event.target.value);
                        }}>
                    </input>
                </div>

                <div className="textfield">
                    <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label>
                    <input 
                    type="email" 
                    className="email" 
                    id="email" 
                    placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" 
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setRegisterEmail(event.target.value);
                        setEmail(event.target.value);
                    }}>
                    </input>
                </div>

                <div className="textfield">
                    <label htmlFor="senha">Senha:</label>
                    <input 
                    type="password" 
                    name="senha" 
                    id="senha" 
                    placeholder="Digite sua senha" 
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setRegisterPassword(event.target.value);
                    }}>
                    </input>
                </div>

                <div class="cursos">
                    <label for="user">Selecione seu curso: 
 </label>
                    <select 
                    name="user" 
                    id="user" 
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setCurso(event.target.value);
                    }}>
                        <option disabled selected> Curso... 
</option>
                        <option value="mtecaai">M-TEC PI | 
 Administração</option>
                        <option value="mtecds">M-TEC PI | 
 Desenvolvimento de Sistemas</option>
                        <option value="mtecaqi">M-TEC PI | 
 Química</option>
                        <option value="etimaai">ETIM 
 Administração</option>
                        <option value="etimds">ETIM 
 Desenvolvimento de Sistemas</option>
                        <option value="erimaqi">ETIM 
 Química</option>
                        <option value="eadaai">Administração - 
 EAD</option>
                        <option value="rh">Recursos 
 Humanos</option>
                        <option value="sec">Secretariado</option>
                        <option value="log">Logística</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="textfield">
                    <label for="data_nascimento">Data de 
 nascimento:</label>
                    <input 
                    type="date" 
                    name="data_nascimento" 
                    id="data_nascimento" 
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setBirthDate(event.target.value);
                    }}>
                    </input>
                </div>

                <button name="submit" id="submit" className="btn- 
 cadastro" onClick={handleRegister}>Cadastrar-se</button>

                <div className="lin2">
                </div>

                <div className="login">
                    <button onClick={VoltarLogin} className="btn- 
voltar">Já tem uma conta?</button>
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   )
   }

  export default Register;'
```

I want to store a birthday date in the cloud firestore in
timestamp, but I am not finding a way to do this.
I haven't found a way to start doing this and everything I find
on the internet is the exact opposite of what I want.
When I pass the date into the firestore, it comes as a string and I want it to be a timestamp, how do i do this?

Comment: What exactly have you found? And what exactly doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: The information is coming as a string, I wanted the date to become timeStamp

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I edited my post and now it is with the complete code, please help me to solve this is an academic work